# How to insert array to array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

**I have arrays**, I don't know how to fix
I already try array_push, array_combine, array_merge, but still nothing.

```
$distance = array(3) {
  [0]=>
  float(2.2)
  [1]=>
  float(1.1)
  [2]=>
  float(3.9)
}
$getID = array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "F"
}
```

**I want to**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> ["B", 2.2]
  [1]=> ["C", 1.1]
  [2]=> ["F", 3.9]
}
```

this is my code

```
function mergeArray($distance, $getID)
{
    $mergeArray = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($distance); $i++) {
        $mergeArray[] = array_splice($getID, $distance[$i]);
    }
    return $mergeArray;
}
```

Edited
help me please thx

Comment: Please show us your attempts and the their results. We're glad to help you sort out specific issues you run into with your implementation, but we're not here to write it all for you (which a proper answer here would require us to)

Comment: @M.Eriksson edited sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) to iterate over two arrays simultaneously and produce a new array:

```
$distance = array(3) {
  [0]=>
  float(2.2)
  [1]=>
  float(1.1)
  [2]=>
  float(3.9)
}
$getID = array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "F"
}

$output = array_map(function ($d, $id) {
    return [$id, $d];
}, $distance, $getID);
```

Note that this code assumes that both arrays have the same length.

**Offtopic:**

A little advice about your code: always name your variable with something that allows you to know what's inside it, using correct plural too:

Your $distance variable contains an array off distances, so it nsme should be in plural.

Your $getID is not a function, so it should not be called get, but just $Ids instead.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need "array_combine()", "array_slice()" or similar. Just iterate through the data and create a new one:

```php
$a = [2.2, 1.1, 3.9];
$b = ["B", "C", "F"];

$new = [];
foreach ($a as $index => $value) {
    $new[] = [
        $b[$index], // Fetch the value with the same index from the other array
        $value
    ];
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/oseSV

Answer (score 0):

```
$distance = [ 2.2, 1.1, 3.9 ];
$getID = [ "B", "C", "F" ];

$result = array_map(fn(string $id, float $distance) => [ $id, $distance ], $getID, $distance);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your current code to work you have to:

- pass both elements to `array_splice` function as an array
- pass the offset of where the function need to replace the value
- as well as the number of how many elements should be removed
- You should not reassign `$mergeArray` because `array_splice` work with pointer

[Checkout the docs for more!](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```php
function mergeArray($distance, $getID)
{
    $mergeArray = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($distance); $i++) {
        array_splice($mergeArray,$i,1, [[
             $distance[$i],
             $getID[$i]
        ]]);
    }
    return $mergeArray;
}
```

however a better approach is to do as in `M. Eriksson`'s ansewar.